# PostgreSQL: could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue that I've been trying to fix but after reading articles, I couldn't do anything about it. The problem is as it follows:
I just installed Apache, php and MySQL on a VPS. Then I had to install PostgreSQL and set up a database and a new user. After running the psql command, I got the following output:

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

So, my question is how do I fix this. I'd be grateful if I receive some feedback.

Comment: How did you create the database and the user?

Comment: DB: 
sudo /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb |
sudo systemctl start postgresql-11 |
sudo systemctl enable postgresql-11 |
I havent created the user yet

Comment: Seems like is gets that a postgres server/db is running BUT you're maybe using an other version than the version which is acutally running. If PG12 is running and you connect expecting a PG13 it will refuse the connection.

Comment: Maybe try a TCP connection? `psql -h localhost ...`?